# JTextArea doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing

```
public class Server extends JFrame{
    private JLabel ipLabel;
    private JTextField ipTextField;
    private JLabel portLabel;
    private JTextField portTextField;

    private JTextArea messagesTextArea;

    public Server(String title){
        super(title);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Container container = getContentPane();
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        ipLabel = new JLabel("IP Address: ");
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        container.add(ipLabel, gc);

        ipTextField = new JTextField();
        ipTextField.setColumns(15);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        container.add(ipTextField, gc);

        portLabel = new JLabel("Port: ");
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        container.add(portLabel, gc);

        portTextField = new JTextField();
        portTextField.setColumns(4);
        gc.gridx = 3;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        container.add(portTextField, gc);

            // I think this is the problem
        messagesTextArea = new JTextArea();
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        container.add(messagesTextArea, gc);
    }
}
```

JTextArea doesn't show up. I am using GridBagLayout. This is my code. What's the problem?

Here's my main method.

```
public class MainFrame {

    private static Server server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                server = new Server("Server");
                server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                server.setBounds(dimension.width/4, dimension.height/4, dimension.width/2, dimension.height/2);
                server.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `main(...)` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always add `JTextArea` to  `JScrollPane` otherwise it will create a problem when the no of rows in text area is greater than frame's height.

```
    JScrollPane jScrollPane=new JScrollPane(messagesTextArea);
    container.add(jScrollPane, gc);
```

and try

```
    gc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.weighty=0.9;
    gc.weightx=0.8;
```

---

use `weighty` and `weightx` to set the size in percent of the component.

use `fill` to fill all the available space either horizontally or vertically or both.

> For more info have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the empty constructor use [JTextArea(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29) to set the row and column size like this:

```
// JTextArea with 1 row and 50 columns
messagesTextArea = new JTextArea(1,50);
```

the constructor without arguments creates a JTextArea with 0 rows and 0 columns hence you see nothing.